# Force twittering-mode links to always open in a specific frame?

Tags: buffers, frames

My (simplified) setup: one frame for twittering-mode and another for w3m, among others, all inside tmux.

While in the twittering-mode frame, `C-m` on a link does one of two things.  Sometimes, the link loads in the w3m frame.  Other times, the twittering-mode frame switches to a w3m buffer, so I have to type `C-x b C-m` to return to twittering-mode after each link I open.

Is there any way to guarantee that the first behavior occurs?  It makes browsing Twitter for articles to read very convenient.  (Load several, read one, type `B` to read another.)

I have tried playing with `display-buffer-alist`, as suggested [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Special_Frames), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650937/reuse-compilation-window-in-another-frame), and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#Choosing-Window), all to no avail.

```
((".w3m.*"
  (display-buffer-reuse-window)
  (reusable-frames . "visible")))
```

Is this not possible?

Comment: I have found the following documentation page to be very helpful when trying to customize how certain buffers are displayed:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html  The bottom of the page has some good examples.

Comment: Clarifying question: when you say "frames," do you mean Emacs's conception of a [frame](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html), or its conception of a [window](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows.html#Windows)?

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice, there's a typo in your alist: I presume you want `display-buffer-reuse-window`, not `...-indow`.

Comment: @Dan, an Emacs frame.  I have several open.  (Typo corrected.)

Comment: I just used `set-frame-name` on the w3m frame. If I could reference that frame in the `reusable-frames` alist, this might work. How would I do that?

Comment: Thank you, @Dan and @lawlist. If I use `display-buffer-in-previous-window` with `inhibit-same-window` set to non-nil, I get the behavior I want. The trick is to ensure that no w3m buffers are in the frame's `buffer-list` parameter. (See the parameters with `(frame-parameters (selected-frame))`.)

Comment: @StevenEdwards: great!  Could you write up and accept your own answer so that future users can see how to do it?

Comment: It's more of a hack than a solution, but certainly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hacky solution is two parts.

First, add this somewhere that'll be evaluated:

```
(add-to-list display-buffer-alist
    (".w3m.*" (display-buffer-in-previous-window)
              (inhibit-same-window . t)
              (reusable-windows . t)))
```

Second, make sure that no `*w3m<#>*` buffers have been seen in your current frame.

```
(frame-parameters (selected-frame))
```

...if you see a w3m buffer in `buffer-list`, you will need to open a new frame.

As long as you never use your twittering-mode frame to visit a w3m buffer, `C-m` on a link will always load in a separate frame.

Comment: A better solution, preferably one that would remove w3m buffers from the frame's `buddy-list` parameter, would be welcome.

Comment: Are you calling `w3m-view-this-url` when selecting a link?  If so, then modifying `w3m-view-this-url-1` seems like the most appropriate custom tailored solution.  Here is a link to an elaborate example of how to select a specific frame to display a certain buffer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489